# How to stream audio from the android mobile to a website?

Tags: android, streaming, audio-streaming, live-streaming

Currently, I want to develop an android mobile app that will be used like a microphone that will be connected to a website in a computer(The server) which it has speakers to output the audio (live streaming ),

The user will speak through the mobile (The microphon app) and at the same time his voice should be output in the website to the speakers.

Another thing , in the website the admin should have the ability to control the mobile application (for example , allow him to speak ,deny him ,and stop him)

I don't know from where I should start ?
And do you know any library could help me in this project?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended with using Twilio as a solution for the problem . Twilio provide a way to communicate using cloud communication , Cloud communications platforms allow developers to embed voice, messaging and video directly into software applications

So I decided to build website as server and mobile app as client , here is the tutorial that I followed 
http://www.sitepoint.com/real-time-video-chat-room/
and here is the twilio documentaion for the mobile client app
https://www.twilio.com/docs/quickstart/php/android-client

I hope that will be usefull for any one want to build an app like mine.